# Using innerHTML to add ordered list fails in IE

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm using the following Javascript code to populate a DIV with an ordered list:

```
// send script back in split list
var scriptList = script.split("\n");
var finalScript = "<ol>\n";
var count = 0;
while(scriptList.length >= count) {
    if((scriptList[count]=="") || (scriptList[count] == undefined))  {
        count ++;
        continue;
    }

    finalScript = finalScript + "<li>" + scriptList[count] + "</li>\n";
    count ++;
}
finalScript = finalScript + "</ol>";
scriptingDiv.innerHTML = finalScript;
```

In firefox, if i look in the DOM using Firebug, this correctly translates to the following and correctly displays an ordered list.

```
<ol>
<li>This is the first item in the list</li>
<li>This is the second item in the list</li>
</ol>
```

In IE, it displays as if the </li> tags are <br /> tags and ignores all the other tags, like this:

> This is the first item in the list
>   This is the second item in the list

Do I need to dynamically add the ordered list to the DOM for this to work? As opposed to just setting the html code in the div using .innerHTML?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to dynamically add the ordered list to the DOM for this to work? As opposed to just setting the html code in the div using .innerHTML?

Yes

```
var scriptList = script.split("\n");
var count = 0;
var ol = document.createElement("ol");

    for(var index=0; index<scriptList.length; index++) {
        if(scriptList[index]!="")  {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML=scriptList[index];
            ol.appendChild(li);
        }
    }

scriptingDiv.appendChild(ol);
```

Comment: +1 (and nearly -1 for sticking with that horrible abuse of the `while` loop…)

Comment: It's still behaving the same way in IE7. :( IE8 works correctly.. Any ideas? We have to support IE7 as that's what most of our users use.

Comment: @Matt: I have tested this script in IE6 (I do not have IE7 right now) and it is working, so your problem must come from somewhere else

Comment: That it is. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use dom methods instead? IE:

```
myOL = document.createElement("ol");
myLI = document.createElement("li");
myTxt = document.createTextNode("My Text!");
myLI.appendChild(myTxt);
myOL.appendChild(myLI);
```

etc